# Caching images UIWebView loaded from htmlString

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I'm using a webview to load a static page from a webservice. I'm saving those pages in a database as a string, and then I load them in an UIWebView like this:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:<myHTMLPage> baseUrl:nil];
```

My problem is that I don't know if external resources like images can be cached and loaded using this strategy.

Request-based UIWebViews can handle it by setting a cachePolicy, but this is not an option for string-based ones (as far as i know).

```
  [self.webView loadRequest:<request> cachePolicy: <policy> timeoutInterval:<interval>];
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!